# My render appear as a silhouette

Tags: rendering, materials

Okay, so my problem is that when I render, the image shows as a silhouette of the object I am trying to render. [image: (Render)] It also appears like this when I go to the rendered viewport [image: rendered viewport]. I have tried:

1. using a lamp with 1000 strength
2. Changing the type of lamp (from sun to spot)
3. Replacing the lamp with a default one (Deleting it and add a new unmodified one)
4. Replacing the lamp with a mesh with an emmision node
5. Replacing the camera with a default one

As you may have guessed none of it has worked.
Here are my world settings

[image: world settings]

And lamp's material settings [image: lamp's material settings]

(I can't insert images for some reason but links are fine so the images are links)
I would like to

Comment: Try deleting the cubes material and adding a new one. Its possible the shader node got disconnected from the output node.

Comment: Could you provide more details about the cube mesh itself (i.e. an image of the node setup, textures used etc.)